# PREFIX-FREE = {$\langle G\rangle$ | G is a CFG where L(G) is prefix-free} is undecidable by reduction to A_{TM}?

Tags: context-free-grammar, turing-machines

Let PREFIX-FREE = {$\langle G\rangle$ | G is a CFG where L(G) is prefix-free}. Prove PREFIX-FREE is undecidable.

I've seen several solutions to PREFIX-FREE by reduction to PCP ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131109/undecidability-of-is-this-cfg-prefix-free)).

In my course we've treated PCP and mPCP superficially (not an essential part of the my course's program) and therefore I'm not able to create a reduction with it.

It is possible to create a valid reduction to $A_{TM}$? I was stuck for a but so I need to know if a reduction like that is possibile.
I don't need a clue I really need to have the reduction (or the bone of that) in order to to help me understand problems of this type (reductions with CFLs that do not use PCP).